# jQuery transfer event bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

For clearing html file inputs it is my understanding that they must be replaced since for security reasons their values cannot be reset using JavaScript.

On these file inputs there are event bindings, what is the easiest way to transfer them to the new file input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)